# How to access Parent Form public variables, control properties and methods? (WinForms C#)

Tags: winforms, variables, properties, controls, parent-child

I have Parent Form `(FrmMainMenu)` that has 3 panels. A panel1 docked on top and a panel2 docked on the left. The 3rd panel will be my container for the child Forms. I have a Title label `(lblTitle.Text = "Home")` on panel1 and buttons on panel2. I'm trying to emulate a Blazor look and feel (navbar and sidebar). My question is how can I access/manipulate the Title label `(lblTitle.Text)` on my Parent Form `(FrmMainMenu)` from a Child Form?

**1. On Control Properties:**
Example Event: When opening the child form I want the `(lblTitle.Text)` properties be changed according to child form function. ex. `(lblTitle.Text = "List of Rooms")`. And when closing the child form I want the  `(lblTitle.Text = "Home")` go back to its original Text properties.

**2. Methods:** I have a method (`public void ResetColors()`) on my `(FrmMainMenu)` that can reset the colors on my buttons. Despite being public method my child form cannot access the method. This is also true to public variables.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

I tried converting private methods and variables into public. I also tried changing the control `Modifiers` to public. I still can't access Parent Form control properties and public methods.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
((frmMainMenu)this.ParentForm).lblTitle.Text = "List of Rooms";
```

**On closing child form:**

```
((frmMainMenu)this.ParentForm).Reset();
((frmMainMenu)this.ParentForm).lblTitle.Text = "Home";
```